# SSLSessionCache not working

Tags: apache, mod-ssl

Am I doing anything wrong in enabling SSL caching?
My configuration:

```
SSLSessionCache "shm:/opt/apps/logs/ssl_cache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default
```

When `LogLevel` is changed to `debug`, I can see that `SSLSessionCache` is initialized, but when I see the server-status URI, all I see is zero stats.

[image: Screenshot of stats]

Why am I not seeing stats similar to http://httpd.apache.org/server-status?

Version: Apache/2.2.25 mod_ssl/2.2.25

Comment: Do you *have* any SSL connections? Anything relevant in the SSL or error log?

Comment: @EJP: All my pages are in SSL and I use mod mellon for SSO. I dont see any errors in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see any SSL traffic because SSL termination was happening at F5.